# Bought joomla template no text after flash content

Tags: html, css, templates, joomla

I have bought a Joomla template from Template monster. It looks like this template isn't Ie8 fully compatible. I can't count on support, because when entering their online chat, you get a fague chat bot.

The problem is that the template doesn't show any text after the flash banner. In FF it all works great, but in Ie7,8 andabove not. Only the top menu and flash header.

**This is the header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
<head>
<base href="http://www.friesecomputerservice.nl/" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="joomla, Joomla" />
<meta name="description" content="Joomla! - the dynamic portal engine and content management system" />
<meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.5 - Open Source Content Management" />
<title>Friese Computerservice</title>

<link href="/index.php?format=feed&amp;type=rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" />
<link href="/index.php?format=feed&amp;type=atom" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/caption.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/theme520/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/theme520/scripts/maxheight.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j('.menu-nav li').hover(
function() {
$j(this).addClass("active");
$j(this).find('.ulwrapper').stop(false, true).slideDown();
$j(this).find('.ulwrapper .ulwrapper').stop(false, true).slideUp('fast');
},
function() {
$j(this).removeClass("active");        
$j(this).find('div').stop(false, true).slideUp('fast');
}
);
$j('.ulwrapper').hover(
function() {
$j('.parent').addClass("active_tab");
},
function() {
$j('.parent').removeClass("active_tab");        
}
);
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/theme520/scripts/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/theme520/scripts/News_Gothic_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/theme520/scripts/cufon-replace.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://info.template-help.com/files/ie6_warning/ie6_script_other.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/theme520/css/constant.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/theme520/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

**This is the body HTML including flash**

```
<div class="flash"><p><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,24" 
width="100%" height="393">
<param name="movie" value="/images/stories/header_v8.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<object data="/images/stories/header_v8.swf" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="393">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
FAIL (the browser should render some flash content, not this).
</object>
<!----> <!--[endif]-->
</object></p></div>
<!--content-->
<div id="content">
<div class="clear">
<!--left-->
<div id="left" class="maxheight">
<div class="left-indent maxheight">
<div class="left-border maxheight">
<div class="left-inner">
            <div class="wrapper-box module_menu">
   <div class="boxTitle">
<h3 >Main Menu</h3>
</div>
        <div class="clear">
<div class="boxIndent">
<ul class="menu"><li class="item1"><a href="/home.html">
<span>Home</span></a></li><li class="item27">
<a href="/joomla-overview.html"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
<li class="item2"><a href="/joomla-license.html">
<span>Joomla! License</span></a></li><li class="item49">
<a href="/news-feeds.html"><span>News Feeds</span></a></li>
<li class="item60"><a href="/wrapper.html"><span>Wrapper</span></a></li>
<li class="item61"><a href="/user.html"><span>User</span></a></li>
<li class="item62"><a href="/poll.html"><span>Poll</span></a></li>
<li class="item63"><a href="/search.html"><span>Search</span></a></li>
<li class="item48"><a href="/web-links.html"><span>Web Links</span></a>
</li></ul>                    </div>
</div>  
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--center-->
<div id="container" class="maxheight">
<div class="clear">
                <table class="blog" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top"><table width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="100%" class="article_column"> <div class="article-title">
<table class="contentpaneopen">
<tr>
<td class="contentheading" width="100%">
<div class="article-title-text">
            Call of Dury - Black Ops       </div>
                                     </td>
                    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="wrapper1-border">
<div class="wrapper1-bg clear">
<div class="article-text-indent">
<div class="clear">
<table class="contentpaneopen">
<tr>
    <td valign="top" colspan="2">                                
    <h1>Call of Duty - Black Ops te koop in Stiens</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article-separator-indent">
<span class="article_separator">&nbsp;</span></div>
</td>
            </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try this it might help you if its the browsers problem http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: A live example instead of a huge amount of code would be much better here.

Comment: Fixed. Joomla has a knd of clean code option in it's editor. That one should be turned off, so it does not trim certain parts of a code. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: should I delete the question, or answer my own question, maybe it's nice for somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI on TinyMCE, if you go into TinyMCE's plugin parameters in Extensions->Plugin Manager->Editor-TinyMCE  the first parameter "Functionality" if you select "Extended" from the drop down list then TinyMCE will have an option to insert/embed media when you are editing your articles.  And it does all the necessary code structure, you just have to select the flash.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Joomla has a kind of clean code option in it's editor. That one should be turned off, so it does not trim certain parts of a code.

Also installing JCE as the default Joomla! WYSIWYG Editor (instead of TinMCE) gave me more options for formatting text, in my case code, there is even a option for formatting or inserting code samples. Inserting code samples combined with turning off clean code option.

Wonderfull.